# Change redirect target URL every X hours

Tags: php, http, web, url, redirect

I am wondering if there is a way I can code a website to redirect to a different target every 24 hours or so, we are wanting to use a referral code from EVE Online on our website, but we'd like it to redirect to a different link every 24 hours or so. This would give all directors a chance to get some rewards and not just one of us.

Is this something that is pssible at all? Or is this too far fetched.

Thanks in advance!

I tried to find the solutions on Google lol

Comment: where you're sending the redirect response, decide then what link to send it to using logic that meets your needs.

Comment: @TZHX how exactly do I do that? I am not familiar with it

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.